# How to override parent :nth-of-type in child element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am using a stylesheet that looks a bit like this:

```
.base-slider {
    width: 100%;

    .ui-state-default {
        border: none;
    }

    .ui-state-default:nth-of-type(1) {
        background: url('left-end-arrow.png');
    }

    .ui-state-default:nth-of-type(2) {
        background: url('right-end-arrow.png');
    }

    /* loads of other style stuff */
}

.secondary-slider {
    .ui-state-default {
        background: url('single-point-arrow.png');
    }
}
```

Then in my html I have something like:

```
<div id="slider" class="base-slider secondary-slider">
   <a href="#" class="ui-state-default">X</a>
</div>
```

The problem I have is that I am seeing the 'left-end-arrow.png' on my `secondary-slider` element rather than the 'single-point-arrow.png' which is what I was expecting

I am guessing that is because `nth-of-type(1)` makes the `base-slider` selector more specific than the child one. Is this correct? And if so, is there any CSS way to say "ignore any previously added pseudo-classes on this element"?

Comment: where is `.ui-state-default` in your HTML?

Comment: .secondary_slider .ui-state-default, .secondary_slider .ui-state-default:nth-of-type(1) { background... } or use !important?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `:nth-of-type(n)` to override the previous pseudo classe styles like this :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/gLvwu/)**

```
 .secondary-slider .ui-state-default:nth-of-type(n) {
     background: url('single-point-arrow.png');
 }
```

**OR**

You can make the second CSS style more specific as you have two calsses on your container, you can use both like this :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/gLvwu/6/)**

```
 .base-slider.secondary-slider .ui-state-default {
     background: url('single-point-arrow.png');
 }
```

Comment: So nth-of-type(n) provides a catch-all override? That is what I needed to know.

Comment: well it is as specific as `nt-of-type(1/2)` selectors but as it is declared after them in the CSS, it overrides them.

Comment: @glenatron: Correct, `:nth-of-type(n)` is a guaranteed match on all elements (well, except one, but that one element is almost never relevant for the purposes of selecting elements).